# Why Linux rm -rf throws Invalid argument error?

Tags: linux, bash

I logged into rhel 7 box (a docker container) and runs as root. I tried to remove a directory and I keep getting Invalid argument error. Here is my command

```
[root@sandbox ~]# rm -rf /var/lib/ambari-server/data/tmp/solr-service/custom-services/SOLR/5.5.2.2.5
rm: cannot remove `/var/lib/ambari-server/data/tmp/solr-service/custom-services/SOLR/5.5.2.2.5': Invalid argument
```

Here is the permission of that folder

```
[root@sandbox ~]# ls -lrth /var/lib/ambari-server/data/tmp/solr-service/custom-services/SOLR/
total 4.0K
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4.0K Nov  7 07:50 5.5.2.2.5
```

The folder is actually empty:

```
[root@sandbox ~]# ls -lrth /var/lib/ambari-server/data/tmp/solr-service/custom-services/SOLR/5.5.2.2.5/
total 0
```

Trying to put the path in quote is not working either:

```
[root@sandbox ~]# rmdir "/var/lib/ambari-server/data/tmp/solr-service/custom-services/SOLR/5.5.2.2.5"
rmdir: failed to remove `/var/lib/ambari-server/data/tmp/solr-service/custom-services/SOLR/5.5.2.2.5': Invalid argument
```

Delete by using inode is not working either:

```
[root@sandbox ~]# ls -il /var/lib/ambari-server/data/tmp/solr-service/custom-services/SOLR/
total 4
98616 drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Nov  7 07:50 5.5.2.2.5
root@sandbox ~]# find . -inum 98616 -exec rm -i {} \; # doesn't throws error but the folder is still there
[root@sandbox ~]# ls /var/lib/ambari-server/data/tmp/solr-service/custom-services/SOLR/
5.5.2.2.5
```

Delete by using find is not working either:

```
[root@sandbox ~]# find /var/lib/ambari-server/data/tmp/solr-service/custom-services/SOLR/ -type d -exec rm -Rf {} \;
rm: cannot remove `/var/lib/ambari-server/data/tmp/solr-service/custom-services/SOLR/5.5.2.2.5': Invalid argument
rm: cannot remove `/var/lib/ambari-server/data/tmp/solr-service/custom-services/SOLR/5.5.2.2.5': Invalid argument
```

How to remove that folder?

Comment: Try put the path inside quotes

Comment: I got the same error:

rm: cannot remove `/var/lib/ambari-server/data/tmp/solr-service/custom-services/SOLR/5.5.2.2.5': Invalid argument

Comment: `rm` with `-f` doesn't produce any output when file to be removed does not exist - so the path is correct but, for some reason, cannot be removed.

Comment: Looks like  a non-standard file name to me. Try `find /var/lib/ambari-server/data/tmp/solr-service/custom-services/SOLR/ -type d  -exec rm -Rf {} \;`

Comment: Try `lsattr <file_name>`.

Comment: @el.pescado Another point to to note. But most likely it is not a problem with attributes..

Comment: @sjsam I tried with find and it is not working as well.

Comment: If the problem is with `rm`, try with `find $dir_path -d`. `-d` argument performs the delete in a similar way to `-exec rm -fr {} \;`. Are there any symbolic links in the path?

Comment: I saw you are using docker, can you post `docker info`? You might need to update docker or change underlying file system

Comment: Are you struck by this issue? https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/62271/unable-to-add-apache-nifi-in-ambari.html

Answer (score 2):

If the folder is empty have you tried the `rmdir`command instead with the full path in simple quotes? ''

If this not work neither could you find the inode of the folder and then remove it via its inode?

```
ls -il <path> #get the inumber, let's say it's 782353
```

Then, `find . -inum <782353> -exec rm -ir {} \;`

Comment: I added your suggestion into the question for better format. It still doesn't work

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention is that the rhel box is a docker container. Could that help debugging?

Comment: have you tried with option -i**r**?

and if you don't have any error... are you sure that this folder is not recreated by a process running on your machine?

Comment: using -ir option still give me the same error: rm: cannot remove `/var/lib/ambari-server/data/tmp/solr-service/custom-services/SOLR/5.5.2.2.5': Invalid argument.

Comment: @SeanNguyen, In the end what was your issue?

Comment: Allan I need to remove that folder to install some program. I am not 100% sure but i think there is a problem between docker and the host that the file cannot be removed from docker container. I think it might related to the comment @gniourf_gniourf point out.